# No se reflejan los cambios de react en mi servidor

Tags: reactjs

Soy nueva con este tema y me encuentro un poco perdida.

Tenemos un proyecto desarrollado en react, una versión anterior se encuentra desplegada en el servidor de pruebas. Hemos realizado varios cambios sobre el proyecto y se actualizaron en el repositorio. Después de hacer pull en nuestro servidor veo que los cambios en el código se actualizaron correctamente pero no se ven reflejados al ingresar a la página.

La verdad no tengo luces de qué me puede faltar o qué debo hacer para que los cambios se vean reflejados. Tenemos nuestro servidor en digital ocean, con apache.

Cualquier ayuda estaré super agradecida.

Comment: Por favor revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así ganar tu primera medalla. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No sé si fue la forma correcta pero logré solucionarlo.

Lo que hice fue eliminar la carpeta build que ya se encontraba dentro de mi proyecto en el servidor y ejecutar de nuevo npm run build, lo cual me creó la carpeta dist. Posteriormente renombré esa carpeta dist a build, copié mi htaccess dentro de la nueva carpeta build y listo, ya funciona correctamente.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).